# Spring boot 2.x deployment issue on weblogic12.1.3 with springdoc-openapi-ui v1.70 jar,failing with error weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic12c, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to deploy the spring boot 2.x application on weblogic 12.1.3. But the deployment is failing with the below error

```
Unable to access the selected application.
java.io.IOException
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException
```

I have found the root cause of this issue, this error is coming when i include the below springdoc dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried deploying the application after removing this dependency and its working.

Here question is, with out this dependency , i cant get the /swagger-ui/index.html link of the api document.

I have even tried using the latest version of this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Same issue even with this. Any one has faced similar issue, if so can some one recommend a solution for this.

Comment: do you have a complete stacktrace to share ?

Comment: Other than the error i posted , i see the below error in the admi logs on the server. 

<admin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <wlsadmin> <> <> <1697046804056> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>